# c# dictionary bound to listbox

Tags: c#, dictionary, listbox, bindingsource

Hi I have a dictionary which I bind to a bindingsource. I would like to display the keys in a listbox. So i add the bindingsource to the listbox and set the displaymember to "Key". This does not work. It gives me the tostring of the dictionary instead of the key string...

Code used:

```
        bs_directions.DataSource = bs_measurements;
        bs_directions.DataMember = "zielwertdict"; //(=Dictionary<string,list<object>>)

        listBox3.DataSource = bs_directions;
        listBox3.DisplayMember = "Key";
```

UPDATE:
The bs_measurements is another list which is bound to another listbox. When I build the project the listBox3 displays the keys of the dictionary. When I change the item in the listbox which is bound to bs_measurement then listbox3 displays the dictionary.Tostring() things... very strange...

UPDATE 2:
The objects contained in the bs_measurment list have a dictionary (zielwerdict) and a hashtable:

```
public class bs_measurementOBject
{
public string name;
public SortedDictionary<string,list>object>> zielwertlist;
public Hashtable block;
}
```

Comment: You may need to set the DataSource to a new BindingSource, i.e; bs_directions.DataSource = new BindingSource(bs_measurements, null);

Comment: this does not change anything

Answer (score 0):

In the above example `bs_directions.DataMember` has to be NULL

Comment: Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.datamember%28v=vs.90%29.aspx  "If the DataSource contains multiple lists (or tables) of data, you should set the DataMember property to the name of one of the sources." But you're only binding to one, correct?

Comment: The objects contained in the bs_measurment list have a dictionary (zielwerdict) and a hashtable.